# A condição do except está sendo lida mesmo com o try dando certo

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, exceção

```
def registerUser(self):
        self.userRegister = self.usernameRegisterEntry.get()
        self.emailRegister = self.emailRegisterEntry.get()
        self.passRegister = self.passwordRegisterEntry.get()
        self.cPassRegister = self.cPasswordRegisterEntry.get()

        self.connDB()

        self.cursor.execute(
            """
            INSERT INTO Users(
                Username,
                Email,
                Password,
                ConfirmPassword
            )
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
        """,
            (
                self.userRegister,
                self.emailRegister,
                self.passRegister,
                self.cPassRegister,
            ),
        )

        try:
            if (
                self.userRegister == ""
                or self.emailRegister == ""
                or self.passRegister == ""
                or self.cPassRegister == ""
            ):
                msgb.showerror(
                    title="Sistema de Login",
                    message="Os dados não podem estar vazios\nPreencha todos os campos corretamente",
                )
            elif len(self.userRegister) < 4:
                msgb.showwarning(
                    title="Sistema de Login",
                    message="O nome de usuário deve ter no mínimo 4 caracteres",
                )
            elif len(self.passRegister) < 8:
                msgb.showwarning(
                    title="Sistema de Login",
                    message="A senha precisa conter no mínimo 8 caracteres",
                )
            elif self.passRegister != self.cPassRegister:
                msgb.showwarning(
                    title="Sistema de Login",
                    message="A senhas não conferem",
                )
            else:
                self.conn.commit()
                msgb.showinfo(
                    title="Sistema de Login",
                    message=f"Parabéns!\n O usuário {self.userRegister} foi registrado com sucesso",
                )
                self.desconnDB()
                self.cleanElementsRegister()
        except:
            msgb.showerror(
                title="Sistema de Login",
                message="Erro no processamento do seu pedido\nPor favor tente novamente",
            )
            self.desconnDB()
```

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Primeiramente, é uma boa prática (FailFast) colocar a validação antes de fazer a inserção no banco de dados; Porquê se já estiver com erro, você valida primeiro antes de sequer tentar inserir e já retorna ali, sem precisar abrir conexão com o banco;

Então colocar a exceção e fazer a exibição dela para ter mais detalhes.
Pode ser que esteja ocorrendo o erro justamente ali nos processos finais da execução, por isso não aparenta;

```
except Exception as e:
msgb.showerror(
                title="Sistema de Login",
                message= str(e) + "\nErro no processamento do seu pedido\nPor favor tente novamente",
            )
```

Comment: Exibindo a exceção com detalhes eu consegui identificar onde o erro estava acontecendo e fazendo a correção o código voltou a funcionar normalmente.